# Partial Views in a Razor Class Library aren't found

Tags: razor, razor-pages

I have a simple RCL with following structure:

`/Pages
    /Shared/
        _Footer.cshtml`

The content is very simple:

```
<h3>  _Footer.cshtml partial view.</h3>
```

I also have a ASP.NET Core Web App project with same folder structure:

`/Pages
    _ViewImports.cshtml
    -ViewStart.cshtml
    /Shared
        _Layout.cshtml`

Somewhere in the layout file I make a reference to the partial view:

`<partial name="_Footer" />`

Here is the problem:

- If I add a Project Reference of RCL to the Web App, the partial view is found and pages render fine.
- If I make a Nuget package from the RCL, add it to a local Nuget source and add a reference to the package, the partial view won't be found.

`The partial view '_Footer' was not found. The following locations were searched: /Pages/_Footer.cshtml /Pages/Shared/_Footer.cshtml /Views/Shared/_Footer.cshtml`

What could be the difference between adding a project reference and Nuget reference? I've verified the Nuget package does contain both the Class Lib's default and views assemblies.

Comment: Any progess on this question?  I see the same behavior.  Referencing a Razor Class Library project works and the page route is found, using a NuGet package of the same project does not locate the page routes.  Look forward to any response here.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: I found a potential answer.  It may be simply that your NuGet package was cached.  You might try running the following from a command prompt:

**dotnet nuget locals all --clear**


I have a sample solution working up at the following url, I may take it down in a few months so hopefully this will help in the short run.


[link](https://github.com/anewton/razorPagesTest)

Answer (score 4):

In my case I wasn't even able to make it work in the scenario the op said it does work:

> If I add a Project Reference of RCL to the Web App, the partial view
>   is found and pages render fine.

I was just getting the standard error message that the partial view was not found (even if the searched paths were correct).

After some head banging I solved this problem by adding the following xml block to both .csproj files:

1. RCL: e.g. RazorUIClassLib.csproj
2. Web App: e.g. WebApp1.csproj

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/sdk), I think you can use `IncludeRazorContentInPack` to include your .cshtml files in a NuGet package (it defaults to false).

Answer (score 3):

I found it works if you use [dotnet pack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack) instead of `nuget pack`. Note for `dotnet pack` package information is now read from [csproj](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj#nuget-metadata-properties) instead of nuget spec file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, the solved writing the full path from the library Area, for example:

In the library i have:

Areas/Footer/Pages/_footer.cshtml

with my UI Proyect i called it like: `<partial name="~/Areas/Footer/Pages/_footer.cshtml" model="My Model instance"/>`

I hope it can help you